# Class Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, class, overloading

This is a very basic operator overload question.
Say I had a class like this...

```
class xy
{
    public:
    double x, y;
    XY(double X, double Y) { x = X; y = Y;}
    XY operator+(const XY & add) const {
        return XY(this->x + add.x, this->y + add.y);
    }
    XY & operator+=(const XY & add) const {?}
    }
}
```

And I want operator+= do to what its supposed to do (you know, add to the current value of x and y). Wouldn't the code be the same for operator+ and operator +=?

Comment: I like this tutorial: http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html

Comment: I recommend the boost operators library for this sort of operator overloading. It allows you to define the minimal set of operations (+= in this case), and then automatically fills out the others (like operator +).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, do the add operation (stick to the `+=` operator), and return a reference to itself.  Oh, and this can't be a `const` method.

```
XY & operator+=(const XY & add) {
   this->x += add.x;
   this->y += add.y;
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: haha that "const" was screwing me up when I tried to change anything pointed to by "this"

Answer (score 5):

How could it be the same? They do different things.

If you don't care about optimizations you can use `+=` in your `+` operator implementation:

```
XY operator + (const XY& right) const
{
    XY left(*this);
    left += right;
    return left;
}
```

Comment: As long as you declare these as inline functions (like they automatically are when defined inside the class) it should not even slow down the performance.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It depends on your copy constructor implementation. It might be faster to call the default constructor and construct the values manually.

Comment: Right. I was referring to this specific class with just two double variables, where default constructor + manual value assignment should not be faster than copy constructor. But of course this does not hold for all classes.

Answer (score 3):

No. Conventionally, `operator+` stores the result in a new object and returns it by value, whereas `operator+=` adds the right-hand side to `*this` and returns `*this` by reference.

The two operators are related -- and can often be implemented in terms of one another -- but they have different semantics and therefore can't have identical implementations.